# Определение и объявление шаблонных методов

Tags: c++

Есть код который находится в разных файлах.
   abc2.cpp

```
template <typename T>
void ABC2::set(std::vector<T> t) {
    n = t.at(0);
}
```

abc.h

```
class ABC2 {
public:
    int n = 0;
    ABC2() {}
    ~ABC2() {}

    template <typename T>
    void set(std::vector<T> t);

};
```

Пытаюсь скомпилировать это, но ошибка на стадии линковки: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ. Вопрос, можно ли определять шаблонный метод нешаблонного класса в другом файле?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Определение шаблонной функции должно находиться в файле .h. Причина в том, что шаблон - это по сути макрос, который надо развернуть на этапе компиляции. Если он недоступен - а он у вас недоступен, потому что находится в другом .cpp файле, - то как раз и будет иметь место неопределенный внешний символ.